# How do I split directory addresses (recusively) in a batch file?

Tags: windows, sqlite, batch-file

I have folders of audio samples, and I'm about to delete what I don't use, but I'd like to have a record of the original contents in an SQLite database.

**Currently, I'm writing directly to the database, but I think writing to a `.CSV` file and importing to a database would be faster because there are hundreds of files.**

Use this batch code to create a directory tree like my file system + dummy files, for testing. It will create within wherever you execute the file. (In my case, the top folder was named `Testing` :

```
SET "BigFish=Z. Unsorted\Big Fish Audio\Midnight Jazz Train\Brass and Winds"
SET "Fragments=Z. Unsorted\Loopmasters\Fragments 02\FR2_SOUNDS_&_FX\FR2_BASS"
SET "LCycles=Z. Unsorted\Loopmasters\Hip-Hop Lunar Cycles\LUN_SYNTH_MELODY_LOOPS"

FOR %%A IN (Tenor_Sax, Trumpet) DO MD "%BigFish%\%%A"
MD "%Fragments%"
MD "%LCycles%"

@echo justtestjunk > "%Fragments%\loop.wav"
@echo justtestjunk > "%LCycles%\drum.aiff"
@echo justtestjunk > "%LCycles%\file.txt"
FOR %%A IN (Tenor_Sax, Trumpet) DO echo justtestjunk > "%BigFish%\%%A\data.sql"
```

With help, I've managed to create a database and make some entries, but my output looks as follows:

[image]

When what I want is this:

[image]

*I think the problem is with the delimiting in the code*.
Also, I need the code to handle the absence of a `Type` value (leaving it `NULL`)

So...

### **Current Code**

```
@echo off

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

SET fld="Z. Unsorted"

sqlite3 %fld%\TestDb.sqlite "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS \"Samples\" (File TEXT NOT NULL, Publisher TEXT, Pack TEXT NOT NULL, Category TEXT, Type TEXT, Size INT);" 

for /r %fld% %%A in (*.aiff *.wav) do (
    call :part "%%~dpA"

    set "File=%%~nxA"
    set "File=!File:'=''!"

    sqlite3 %fld%\TestDb.sqlite "INSERT OR REPLACE INTO \"Samples\" VALUES ('!File!', '!Publisher!', '!Pack!', '!Category!', '!Type!', '%%~zA');"

    @echo '!File!', '!Publisher!', '!Pack!', '!Category!', '%%~zA'
)

PAUSE

:part
    for /f "tokens=6-10 delims=\" %%A in ("%~1") do (
        set "Publisher=%%~A"
        set "Publisher=!Publisher:'=''!"

        set "Pack=%%~B"
        set "Pack=!Pack:'=''!"

        set "Category=%%~C"  
        set "Category=!Category:'=''!"

        set "Type=%%~D"  
        set "Type=!Type:'=''!"
    )
```

Comment: Batch files have no native method to read the metadata of a file.

Comment: I'm not after metadata. I'm logging parts of the file path and the file name. (and, optionally, file size). I've made some progress; so I'll update the question. One link that helped was [this one](https://www.computerhope.com/forum/index.php?topic=134599.0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "fld=Z. Unsorted"

> "%fld%\TestDb.sql" (
    echo BEGIN;
    echo CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "Samples" ^(File TEXT NOT NULL, Publisher TEXT, Pack TEXT NOT NULL, Category TEXT, Type TEXT, Size INT^);
)

for /r "%fld%" %%A in (*.aiff *.wav) do (
    set "relative_path=%%~dpA"
    set "relative_path=!relative_path:%cd%=!"
    if "!relative_path:~,1!" == "\" set "relative_path=!relative_path:~1!"

    call :part "!relative_path!"

    set "File=%%~nxA"
    set "File='!File:'=''!'"

    >> "%fld%\TestDb.sql" echo INSERT OR REPLACE INTO "Samples" VALUES ^(!File!, !Publisher!, !Pack!, !Category!, !Type!, %%~zA^);

    @echo !File!, !Publisher!, !Pack!, !Category!, !Type!, %%~zA
)

>> "%fld%\TestDb.sql" echo COMMIT;

sqlite3 -cmd ".read '%fld%\TestDb.sql'" "%fld%\TestDb.sqlite" ""

pause
exit /b

:part
    for /f "tokens=2-5 delims=\" %%A in ("%~1") do (
        set "Publisher=%%~A"
        if defined Publisher (
            set "Publisher='!Publisher:'=''!'"
        ) else set "Publisher=NULL"

        set "Pack=%%~B"
        if defined Pack (
            set "Pack='!Pack:'=''!'"
        ) else set "Pack=''"

        set "Category=%%~C"
        if defined Category (
            set "Category='!Category:'=''!'"
        ) else set "Category=NULL"

        set "Type=%%~D"
        if defined Type (
            set "Type='!Type:'=''!'"
        ) else set "Type=NULL"
    )
exit /b
```

The code uses `enabledelayedexpansion` for some variables. That is
for variables using `!` instead of `%`.

Uses a `for` loop to parse directories using recursion to find files.

The `call :part "!relative_path!"` line gets the parts of the path of `%fld%`
that match the columns values of Publisher, Pack, Category and Type.

Then it goes through the files in that directory and inserts the
sql statements into the sql file.

The sql inserted values that may contain `'` are escaped to be `''`.

The `for` loop in the label `:part` uses tokens of `2-5`. This will
set `%%A` to `Publisher`, `%%B` to `Pack`, `%%C` to `Category` and
`%%D` to `Type`. Adjust token setting of `2-5` to what is needed to
match the path segments.

Current variables set in label `:part` are set as `NULL` if the variable
is not defined else the variable is single quote escaped and outer
single quotes are added. Thus, ready for insert as is. Similar done
to the `File` variable in the `for` loop.

The `relative_path` variable is the absolute path with `%cd%` removed
from it and possible leading backslash removed. It should be easier to
tokenize in the `for` loop in the label of `:part`.

Comment: Someone suggested it was a bad idea to make multiple databases and multiple tables; so, I am changing to script to make only one database with a single table - then I can use SQL to filter. I really appreciate the work you put in to help. - about to get started tweaking this code. :)

Comment: That helped tremendously! I have one last problem: There isn't always a Category folder, and there is never a Type (I have to enter type manually), and when I run the script it returns an error `table has 6 columns but 5 values were supplied` - otherwise the output is fine. >> `'Soundfile.wav', 'PrimeAudio', 'Airborne Sound - Human', ''=''', ''=''', '4040842'`

Comment: The pics in your updated question shows that a shift in tokens was needed i.e. perhaps change of `6-10` to `4-8`. Will update my answer with question changes. Thanks for the setup script for the test environment.

Comment: I'm running the script on the real files now, and it's working! Wow, I'm impressed by your work. This gives me a lot more to read up on about batch scripts!